# Vuejs with vue-socket-io integration connection refused error

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vue-socket-io](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) with **vuejs2** but facing a problem in the start. I can't seem to make a connection with socket-io. I have followed the exact documentation but every time the call goes it gets an error of 404 not found.

> build.js?a270:1 GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L-T2-Vp 404

This is the error I am getting on the console

> @ ./src/main.js 5:0-33
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

I haven't added much line of code in main.js file. Here is the main block that is adding socket

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';

Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:8080/');
```

Comment: You'll get more useful help if you clarify some details. Which documentation are you looking at? What is the `main.js` file you're referring to? If you're modifying the `main.js` file in the `vue-socket.io` library, then that's probably you're problem. `vue-socket.io` is not a skeleton project that you add your code to, it's a library that you're supposed to use to build your own project. If you modify the library itself, don't be surprised if it ends up breaking.

Comment: did you find an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create js file and put this code.

```
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(4113);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //console.log('connected');
    socket.on('event_name', function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        io.emit('event_name', data);
    });

});
```

than you have to install express and sockt-io from terminal when server start than your error will be resolve

run this file : go your path where located file and run **node file_name**

now, install vue-socket.io vie npm then in main.js file create an instance like:

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io';
Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:4113');
```

now, you have to put code in your . vue file

```
sockets: {
    connect() {
      // Fired when the socket connects.
      this.isConnected = true;
      console.log("server connected");
    },

    disconnect() {
      this.isConnected = false;
      console.log("server disconnected");
    },

    // Fired when the server sends something on the "messageChannel" channel.
    messageChannel(data) {
      this.socketMessage = data
    }
    }
```

now, create to emit server method by this methods...

```
 pingServer() {
      console.log("click");
      this.$socket.emit('pingServer', 'PING!')
      },
```